# Problems to connect with remote redis-server

Tags: amazon-ec2, redis

I have two Amazon-EC2 instance let's say A and B.
B has redis-server installed.

I want to access B from A So I am trying

```
A$ redis-cli -h B_ip -p 6379
Could not connect to Redis at B_ip:6379: Connection timed out
Could not connect to Redis at B_ip:6379: Connection timed out
```

**My workaround :**

I changed /etc/redis/redis.conf

```
bind 127.0.0.1    ---->   bind 0.0.0.0
```

Then I restarted redis-server but the issue is persistent

**More informations :**

```
B$ netstat -nlpt | grep 6379
(Not all processes could be identified, non-owned process info
 will not be shown, you would have to be root to see it all.)
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:6379                0.0.0.0:*                   LISTEN      -
```

Please help.

**Progress** :

I searched and found to remove `bind` at all to get connected from external ip. But again not working.
I tried to replace `bind 0.0.0.0`  with private_ip_of_B but still not working.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Port 6379 doesn't need to be open for the EC2 servers, but it does need to be open for the Redis server.

Can you check that port is 6379 opened in your AWS security group. And try again.

And make sure you are using private ip not the public one.

Comment: Yep, this worked for me. In my case, even though the port and IP was open properly, I was connecting to the external AWS IP. Thanks

Comment: In my case I was trying to connect to the public IP, thanks :)

Comment: How to obtain the private IP from Redis Cloud? I am not using any AWS/GCP Server rather redis cloud that gives you ready to use instances, there I can only see option for public IP and SAML password